# Showing last eight characters of a decrypted string in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, encryption

At the moment, I have a field within my Laravel project that requires some form of encryption, so I use the available encryption through Laravel, and decrypt using the following in my blade:

```
{{\Crypt::decryptString($e->SCEIN)}}
```

But I was curious if there was a way for me to be able to show only the last 8 characters of this field after it has been decrypted. I can't seem to find much mention of it though I do know using `substr` would technically get me there, I am not sure how to use it on an encrypted field.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the whole decrypt string inside the `substr` function and setting `-8` in the second param will give you the last 8 characters.

```
{{ substr( \Crypt::decryptString($e->SCEIN), -8 ) }}
```